# Python multiply string column with daterange

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which appears as following:

```
list_name
---------
list1
list2
...
```

I try to the multiply each row with a date range :

```
start = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2025, 1, 1)
daterange = pd.date_range(start, end)
```

Desired result is the following:

```
list_name|   date
---------|  --------
list1    |  2019-01-01
list1    |  2019-01-02
list1    |  2019-01-03
  ...    |       ...
list1    |  2025-01-01
list2    |  2019-01-01
list2    |  2019-01-02
list2    |  2019-01-03
  ...    |       ...
list2    |  2025-01-01
```

I am not sure how to explode it across the rows.

Comment: `from itertools import product; pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.list_name, daterange)), columns=['list_name', 'date'])`.

Comment: With a newer version of `pandas` you could `cross` `merge` your DataFrame with a DataFrame of the dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution, thanks to [@QuangHoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang)'s comment:

```py
from itertools import product

pd.DataFrame(list(product(df.list_name, daterange)), columns=['list_name', 'date'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `pd.merge(how = 'cross')` to achieve this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'list_name' : ['list1', 'list2']
})
start = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2025, 1, 1)
daterange = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start, end))
pd.merge(df, daterange, how = 'cross')df = pd.DataFrame({
    'list_name' : ['list1', 'list2']
})
start = datetime.date(2019, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date(2025, 1, 1)
daterange = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range(start, end))
pd.merge(df, daterange, how = 'cross')
```